# ELK Stack search_phase_execution_exception all shards failed Error

Tags: elasticsearch, elk

I am using elastic search to view application logs from different applications and servers. When i try to run a query i get the error:

```
search_phase_execution_exception all shards failed Error: Bad Request at Fetch._callee3$ (http://172.21.7.136:5601/33984/bundles/core/core.entry.js:34:109213) at l (http://172.21.7.136:5601/33984/bundles/kbn-ui-shared-deps/kbn-ui-shared-deps.js:368:155323) at Generator._invoke (http://172.21.7.136:5601/33984/bundles/kbn-ui-shared-deps/kbn-ui-shared-deps.js:368:155076) at Generator.forEach.e.<computed> [as next] (http://172.21.7.136:5601/33984/bundles/kbn-ui-shared-deps/kbn-ui-shared-deps.js:368:155680) at fetch_asyncGeneratorStep (http://172.21.7.136:5601/33984/bundles/core/core.entry.js:34:102354) at _next (http://172.21.7.136:5601/33984/bundles/core/core.entry.js:34:102670)
```

I have read various response on this error and tried out a few including avoiding replicas since i am running on a single node, increasing memory capacity and even restarting applications multiple times. Whenever i restart the elastic search and logstash containers and run an avoid replicas command on elastic search, my query is processed after which the above error persists for subsequent queries.

Please how can I fix this ?

Comment: Can you share your query and index mapping and setting ?

Comment: It's actually the default query that kibana makes when you click on the discover button after creating a widecard index pattern.